# Are PS/2 devices port mapped I/O devices?

Tags: linux-kernel, port, hardware, pci, bus

Are `PS/2` devices like old-style mice and keyboard are `port mapped I/O` devices? Are there any `PCI` or `USB` devices which can be functioning as `port mapped I/O` devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PS/2 keyboard controller is accessed via I/O ports 60h and 64h.

PCI and PCIe devices can provide either MMIO mapped or I/O mapped address ranges or both.

USB devices can only be accessed via the USB controller, which uses MMIO, not I/O ports.